# Get new graphic card for HP ENVY 27-p011?

Tags: graphics-cards, desktop

What I want to ask is does this computer can get new graphic card ? And how can I assemble it ? Also what kind of graphic card should I get to not get the GPU bottleneck ? P/S:Sorry for my bad English and the computer details is here https://support.hp.com/in-en/document/c04874664

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## You can't really.

Per the specs page:

> Discrete AMD R7 A365 GPU: Permanently soldered to the motherboard and is not in card form factor

There's also no Thunderbolt, so an eGPU using that is out of the question.

The only option left would be to do use one of the PCI-e equipped M.2 slots [on the motherboard](https://support.hp.com/in-en/document/c04854832) and some sort of [M.2 to PCI-e riser](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B073WG56FV).

[image]
[image]

However, I would strongly discourage this, as it'll be [extremely difficult to actually modify your PC to work as such.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nS2CsCy5l5c)

Comment: I Just get a little feel it waste because it is Intel core i7 CPU but it can't get to play a game that Intel core i3 can play smoothly with some cheap CPU like astroneer

Comment: @AlphaBetA You could always sell it and buy something else, or just remove the CPU and put it in a normal desktop motherboard. Neither are perfect solutions.

Comment: Also i don't want to sell it but how to remove the CPU and put it in another motherboard while it still get in the computer case ? Because the  screen is very big and it will be very cool to play game in the   screen big like that

Comment: Unfortunately AFAIK there's no way to easily keep using the display. Tough spot :/